# Google Sheets: Plus (+) and Multiply (*) input, odd behaviour

Tags: google-sheets, input, layout, keyboard

Google Sheets is showing a weird behaviour on Firefox, W10, but it also happens in Brave Browser and Ubuntu:

Using an Italian Keyboard (with Italian Layout), whenever I'm parsing a formula, I click on a cell to reference and then use either + or *, the continuation of the text is displaced 1 character to the left, as in the [following GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zpum.jpg).

It does not happen when I change the layout to US English: in this case, the intermitent "type bar" stays at the right of the operator, as expected.

What is going on? This issue is specific to Google Sheets, Excel or other programs do not seem affected.

Thanks!

Comment: Web Development is probably one of the most finicky fields. A lot of the problems come from settings and context. So you are right for including the search engine and the keyboard layout. [I would report this to the google devs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/4431192?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)